# Construir la variable de un array

Tags: html, jquery, array

Tengo varios *array*:

```
var ca_menu=["texto1","texto2", etc]
var cs_menu=["texto1","texto2", etc]
var fr_menu=["texto1","texto2", etc]
```

Para añadir los valores de un *array* a un HTML, el nombre de la variable del     *array* lo construyo con 3 variables:

```
variable1="ca"; //Es una de las tres opciones que obtengo según unas condiciones determinadas)
variable2="_menu"; //(siempre el mismo)
variable_final=variable1+variable2;
```

Así `variable_final` me da el nombre del *array* a utilizar, en este caso: **`ca_menu`**

Paso a añadir los valores al HTML utilizando `variable_final` para llamar al *array*:

```
a=0;
while(a<variable_final.lenght){
  $("objeto").append("<li>"+variable_final[a]+"</li>");
  a++;
};
```

Pero, resulta que el valor de `variable_final` que es `ca_menu`, lo interpreta como un texto y no llama al *array* correspondiente, y el resultado es:

```
<li>c</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>_</li>
<li>m</li>
etc.
```

Cuando quisiera que fuera:

```
<li>texto1</li>
<li>texto2</li>
etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay mejores forma de hacer lo que planteas, pero una solución de acuerdo a lo que muestras sería usando la función [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval):

```
array: 
a=0;
while(a<variable_final.lenght){
  $("objeto").append("<li>"+eval(variable_final)[a]+"</li>");
  a++;
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya no me acordaba de esta función. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

porque `variable1` y `variable2` son de tipo `string`, cuando las sumas `variable_final = variable1 + variable2` siguen siendo del tipo string.

para poder hacer lo que tú dices, yo te recomendaría meterlos en un json

```
all_menus = {}
all_menus['ca_menu'] = ["texto1","texto2", etc]
all_menus['cs_menu'] = ["texto1","texto2", etc]
all_menus['fr_menu'] = ["texto1","texto2", etc]
```

Luego haces lo que antes hacías

```
variable1="ca"; //Es una de las tres opciones que obtengo según unas condiciones determinadas)
variable_final=variable1+ "_menu"; //si va a ser estática no vale la pena asignarla a una variable
```

después hacer tu llamada de función

```
array: 
a=0;
while(a<all_menus[variable_final].lenght){
    $("objeto").append("<li>"+all_menus[variable_final][a]+"</li>");
    a++;
};
```